# Overload operator with template, but prevent redefinition

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I want to define specialization of `operator<<` using a template, but I don't want it to break the behavior of this operator if it's already defined for some data type.

```
enum State {Open, Locked};
enum Input {Coin, Push};

std::string ToString(State c){
  switch (c) {
    case Locked : return "Locked";
    case Open : return "Open";
  }
}

std::string ToString(Input c){
  switch (c) {
    case Coin : return "Coin";
    case Push : return "Push";
  }
}

template<typename T>   //obviously, a bad idea
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, T c) {
  return s<<ToString(c);
}
```

later in code I'd like to use:

```
int main() {
  std::cout<<Coin<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<Open<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<std::string("normal string")<<std::endl;
}
```

Unsurprisingly, above gives compilation error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
   std::cout<<std::string("normal string")<<std::endl;
```

(many more follow)

Q: How to tell the compiler to ignore template, if the function / operator already has a definition?

Comment: SFINAE on `decltype(ToString(c))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can employ [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to make the template instantiation only valid for the types supported by the overloads of `ToString()`, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(ToString(std::declval<T>()))>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, T c) {
  return s<<ToString(c);
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/RDGVA3913)

Comment: Can you explain, how does it exactly work in this case? 
Does the substitution fails for T others than `State` and `Input` because `ToString(std::declval<T>())` cannot be evaluated?
Also, this solution works in this case, and thank you for that, but, out of curiosity, is it possible to do it the way I stated in my question? By making the compiler check if there's another definition of `operator<<` before using template?

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski "Does the substitution fails for T others than `State` and `Input` because `ToString(std::declval<T>())` cannot be evaluated?" Yes. Then the instantiation for these types won't participate in overload resolution. For the 2nd question, AFAIK, no. We can only define our operator overloads, then all the overloads will be picked up and determined which one should be used by overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto what [@songyuanyao answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352238/817643), do two more things:

1. Wrap you code in a namespace.
2. Fully qualify the identifier in `decltype` by the namespace. I.e. something like `decltype(MyNS::ToString(std::declval<T>()))`.

Your print statements will still work on account of ADL, but you won't run a-foul the lookup rules if your operator is somehow a candidate with a type that also defines `ToString` in *another* namespace.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> If you have any templates in your namespace, than ADL will consider the namespaces of their parameters as well. Which can put you at the mercy of another `ToString` definition during unqualified lookup.

Comment: Of course, that was just some experiments, not part of any bigger project. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out I can do it using **C++ concepts**

```
template<typename T>
concept bool HasToString = requires(T a) {
  { ToString(a) } -> std::string;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, HasToString c) {
  return s<<ToString(c);
}
```

This requires **gcc.6** and `-fconcepts` compilation flag.